# jquery drag and drop связи

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, drag-n-drop

Что хочу получить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка для визуализации. Задача состоит в том что бы связывать блоки (динамически протянуть стрелку от одного блок к другому) и в конце получить структуру для дальнейшей работы. Например:

a link to b

b link to c

Так же у одного блок может быть несколько связей. Прошу подсказать направление, как сделать связи.

перетаскивания сделал так:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; }
  #draggable1 { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вас что-то в этом духе интересует? http://graphonline.ru/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Рабочий вариант, но код не в лучшем виде. [Ссылка](http://plnkr.co/edit/OO2BaEyxEFTkLmrdL0g5?p=preview) на plunker.

```js
"use strict";

var can = $("#can").get(0), ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var boxes = [];

function get_box(x, y) {
  for (var box of boxes) {
    if (x >= box.x && x < box.x + box.w && y >= box.y && y < box.y + box.h) {
      return box;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function getxy(e) { return {x:e.clientX, y:e.clientY}; }

class Box {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
    this.w = w; this.h = h;
    this.drag = null;
    this.name = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt() + boxes.length);
    boxes.push(this);
  }
  on_mouse_down(e) { 
    this.drag = {
      oldx: this.x, oldy: this.y, // old position of box
      msx: e.clientX, msy: e.clientY // mouse start x, y
    };
  }
  on_mouse_move(e) {
    if (!this.drag) return;
    var dx = e.clientX - this.drag.msx, dy = e.clientY - this.drag.msy;
    this.x = this.drag.oldx + dx;
    this.y = this.drag.oldy + dy;
    draw_boxes();
  }
  on_mouse_up(e) {
    this.drag = null;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    ctx.font = "30px Georgia";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText(this.name, this.x + 10, this.y + 30);
    ctx.restore();
  }
  center() {
    return {x: this.x + Math.floor(this.w/2), y: this.y + Math.floor(this.h/2) };
  }
}

var link = null, links = [];

function on_mouse_event(method_name) {
  return function (e) { for (var box of boxes) box[method_name](e); }
}
$("#can").mousedown(function (e) {
  var p = getxy(e), b = get_box(p.x, p.y);
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    new Box(p.x, p.y, 50, 50);
    draw_all();
    return;
  }
  if (!b) return;
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    link = {b};
    return;
  }
  get_box(p.x, p.y).on_mouse_down(e);
});
$("#can").mousemove((e) => { 
  if (link) {
    link.t = getxy(e);
  } else {
    for (var box of boxes) box.on_mouse_move(e);
  }
  draw_all();
});
$("#can").mouseup((e) => { 
  var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY, b = get_box(x, y);
  if (link) {
    if (link.b == b || !b) {
      link = null;
      return;
    }
    links.push({from:link.b, to:b});
  } else {
    for (var box of boxes) box.on_mouse_up(e);
  }
  link = null;
});

$("#getlinks").click((e) => {
  var msg = "";
  for (var l of links) {
    msg += `Box "${l.from.name}" свзяан с Box "${l.to.name}"<br>`;
  }
  $("#res").html(msg);
});

new Box(10, 10, 50, 50);
new Box(150, 150, 50, 50);

function draw_boxes() {
  for (var box of boxes) {
    box.draw();
  }
}

function draw_links() {
  for (var l of links) {
    var bc1 = l.from.center(), bc2 = l.to.center();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(bc1.x, bc1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(bc2.x, bc2.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function draw_link() {
  var bc = link.b.center();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(bc.x, bc.y);
  ctx.lineTo(link.t.x, link.t.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function draw_all() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
  draw_links();
  draw_boxes();
  if (link) draw_link();
}

draw_all();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="can" width="300" height="300">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
  </canvas>
</div>

<hr>MouseMove -- перемещение коробок.
<br>Shift + Click -- добавить коробку.
<br>Ctrl (на коробке) + MouseMove -- провести линию.
<br>
<hr>
<button id="getlinks">Получить все связи</button>
<p id="res"></p>
```

Comment: А  каким способом в конце можно получить список что с чем связано ?
Что-то вроде, а связано с б, б связано с с, с связано с а.

Comment: @santer, все связи находятся в массиве `links`. Каждая связь это объект вида `{from: box1, to: box2}`. Можно всем `box'ам` дать имена и тогда все связи можно получить так:
`for (var link of links) console.log(link.from.name, link.to.name);`

Comment: @santer, объясните для чего вам это.

Comment: Это нужно для фронтенда, т.е пользователь рисует определенную схему, дальше на основание этих связей делаются действия на бэкенде

Comment: @santer, добавил кнопку с получением всех связей. Надеюсь я вам помог.